# How to write a Window Server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, gnustep

how can i write a windowserver for gnustep? i'm reading the source of gnustep some days but don't get how this works. Can someone please explain how it works from NSApplicationMain() to a graphical user interface? What is needed to implement a very basic WindowServer? I know this is quite a big topic.

Thanks,
Tommy

Answer (score 0):

GNUstep uses its own semi-abstract class in its AppKit called GSDisplayServer to implement a wrapper around existing windowing system like X11 or WIN32. It's also up to your design of this WindowServer but there will be mainly two things to do, the first thing is to implement your own WindowServer that provide the APIs you need (if existed, wouldn't it be some Quartz APIs?) and an implementation of a backend (subclassing GSDisplayServer and NSGraphicsContext). But as I know the only way to get a window on OSX requires you to use Objective-C with NSWindow as there is no supported API to create a window on OSX without Objective-C anymore (please correct me here as my knowledge is limited to GNUstep side). So I think it is not making much sense to implement a WindowServer for GNUstep rather wrap it around any existing windowing system on your system. But seriously, X11 is not that bad, and I'd strongly recommend you to use it. Rewriting GNUstep's x11 backend in xcb, at least. Inventing a new windowing system would be a big waste of time. GNUstep would benefit more if you contribute your time in the other areas. But if you just want to port GNUstep to your windowing system, just look at the existing backends.

Comment: thanks for the answer! :) for your information: i'd like to program a ZUI window server.

Comment: Isn't that like making an X11 window manager that manage windows in OpenGL? Unless you plan to do things like locking font size while zooming. If not, you could just implement it in X11.